# How to get USB/Bluetooth GPS Receiver Location Using Java SE

Tags: java, gps

I have a usb/bluetooth gps receiver and I would like to know how could I get the gps location using Java SE Desktop? I couldn't find information for java se. Is there any example?

Thanks

Comment: Simon's almost certainly correct, but please post the model of GPS receiver you have so we can be sure.

Comment: @JeremyP It's a Globalsat BT-328

Comment: Simon's answer is correct.  This review tells me it does use NMEA on a serial port. http://www.pocketgpsworld.com/globalsat-bt-328-gps-review.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most USB GPS receivers I know provide the data on a (virtual) serial port in [NMEA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NMEA_0183)-format.

So you have to connect to the serial port to read the data. I have never used a serial port in Java, but I guess there are many docs and tutorials out there. Maybe this [Wikibook](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Serial_Programming/Serial_Java) is a good starting point.