# GPS over USB Example for Java, or some other Windows program?

Tags: java, gps, usb

I am looking to record movement based on GPS, and plan to record it on the laptop that is in the vehicle. It looks like GlobalSat BU-353 is a good pick, but I am not clear on how to write a program for the actual receive/record. The [existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7790075/how-to-get-usb-bluetooth-gps-receiver-location-using-java-se) seems to be fore Serial, and [does not appear to be helpful for USB systems](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Serial_Programming/Serial_Java). I could use a USB-to-serial converter with a Serial based GPS device, but I don't like this complexity.

- Can you point me a working example? I don't mind using a foreign language (Python perhaps), as long as I can run it on Windows without too much installation/programming headache. Please point me to evidence that this can be done, and how. Preferably a working example that was tested with x USB receiver.
- Also I would like information on what the risk of compatibility problems there would be. I would expect that there are many programs out there along with many GPS devices so that a standard has been established (like USB cameras), but is this really the case?

Answer (score 0):

Look up Prolific Technology USB-to-serial converter software.  You install it, then your USB device data can be read off of one of Windows COM ports.  I'm using the RXTX library to read the com port that is getting my USB data (RXTXcomm.jar).

It's a bit of a pain, because you don't know for sure which COM port is going to be used, it can depend on the order things are plugged into the USB ports on the machine, etc.  On some machines, the same physical USB port tends to gravitate towards the same COM port, however, so maybe that will make things predictable enough.  Anyway, that's what I'm using to read USB data.  At least it's the installed converter, which does not involve code, and everything is java from there.

Yes, there is a defacto standard for the GPS output, the NMEA data strings.  All the USB GPS devices I've come across use this.  Essentially, as soon as they're turned on (which means as soon as they're plugged in), they start emitting strings of data in the NMEA format.  The first letters designate what kind of record is being reported, and the rest of the string is the data.  I'm sure some of them also have query capability, etc., but given the nature of GPS programs in general it also works in a lot of cases just to have the device spit out the characters until someone unplugs it.  Each string is less than some reasonable maximum number of characters (80?  132?  don't remember), and is terminated with some kind of EOL.  My code reads them all and only processes the ones it's interested in.

Hope that gets you started.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, very helpful. I have a question about what you were using: Was the GPS device itself a USB device? or was it a serial device with USB converter?

Comment: I am hoping not to use a serial adapter for aesthetic reasons, I am gonna use a straight USB solution if I can, but I don't know yet whether it works the same / does a straight USB solution use a COM port?

Comment: Prolific Technology USB-to-serial converter software seems to only bring up results for the drivers of serial solutions with USB converters.

Comment: I see why you had trouble finding it.  I only managed after I looked up a product number under Programs and Features.  Try http://prolificusa.com/pl-2303hx-drivers/

My devices were all USB dongles; no adapter.  This software allows you to plug in a USB device and read it as though it were plugged into an old-fashioned COMn port.  You do have to figure out whether you need to read COM1, COM2, etc. for a given device; plug in your device and then look in Device Mgr to see which com port just went active.  

Then the rxtx library will give you all-Java access to the COMn ports.

Comment: Did that get things going for you?